# How to wrap several bootstrap classes with LESS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I have downloaded the original bootstrap LESS files, and in my html file I have the following code which works perfectly:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
<div class="my-cell">
```

and in my less file have:

```
.my-cell{
   .col-md-04;
   .col-md-offset-8;
}
```

But i get an error from Visual Studio's less compiler:
    "Undeclared mixin"

[image]

the less files is found, because the following line works:

```
.col-xs-12;
```

How can I wrap several twitter-bootstrap less classes in into one class?

Answer (score 1):

If you have less files, you should have mixins.less file as well. Go through it and there are many mixins available to make a column, row or a grid, etc. Copied some of there here but check the actual source file that you have downloaded.

Also, don't forget to include your mixin.less file before using it in your less file like t his:

```
@import "mixins.less"; //path of the file - relative to the path of file you are writing your less code.



// Below is some code from mixins.less but refer the actual file.
// Creates a wrapper for a series of columns
.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
  margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
  .clearfix();
}

// Generate the extra small columns
.make-xs-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}

// Generate the small columns
.make-sm-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  // Calculate width based on number of columns available
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Generate the small column offsets
.make-sm-column-offset(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    margin-left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-sm-column-push(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-sm-column-pull(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    right: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Generate the medium columns
.make-md-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  // Calculate width based on number of columns available
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Generate the medium column offsets
.make-md-column-offset(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    margin-left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-md-column-push(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-md) {
    left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-md-column-pull(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    right: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Generate the large columns
.make-lg-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  position: relative;
  // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
  min-height: 1px;
  // Inner gutter via padding
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);

  // Calculate width based on number of columns available
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}

// Generate the large column offsets
.make-lg-column-offset(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    margin-left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-lg-column-push(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    left: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
.make-lg-column-pull(@columns) {
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    right: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
  }
}
```

And after importing the mixin file, just use it like:

```
.my-cell{
      .make-md-column(@columns; @gutter: @grid-gutter-width); //pass the parameters accordingly. for grid, gutter you can use variables.less file as well as the defaults are already defined there
}
```

Comment: To get the behaviour of: "col-md-12". What mixin(s) should i use? .make-md-column-pull(4) ?

Comment: @thinus I believe its `.make-md-column(12);` or pass the gutter as well if you don't want the default one.

Comment: @thinus also, make sure you have row defined in the parent element somewhere or you can also use `.make-row();` if you have not defined in html semantics.

Comment: .make-md-column does not exist. but .make-md-column-pull/push/offset does

Comment: @thinus may be something is wrong with your less files. you can check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) all those useful mixins are mentioned on the site.

Comment: Just downloaded a fresh source bundle from getbootstrap.com . And still no make.md-column. Maybe there is an error with Web Essentials Less compiler.. :/

Comment: @thinus ignore that one. first check if your layout is fine when you run your application.

Comment: @thinus also make sure you have the latest version of web essentials installed.

Comment: I have "Web Essentials 2012 3.2" - the newest version for VS2012. The layout does not look fine, because no CSS file is outputtet. Im only compiling LESS in VS2012, not in the browser.

Comment: @thinus make sure you have imported mixins.less in your new .less file and open the mixin file and search for .make-md-column. And refer the link that I have given above to how to use it.